# How to retrieve an image in jqgrid from SQL server database in MVC 5 EF 6

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, jqgrid

I am totally new to JQuery grid and I want to retrieve an image to my jqgrid from sql server database in asp.net mvc 5 ef6(code first). I am stuck at controller level and I am not able to write the code at controller level. I have two variables public byte[] pic1 and public byte[] pic2. Need help further. Thanks...

I have my model as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace JQueryPortal.Models
{
    public class VehicleInLog
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string SystemRefNo { get; set; }
        public string LCode { get; set; }
        public string TagNo { get; set; }
        public DateTime RecDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime RecTime { get; set; }
        public string RegNo { get; set; }
        public float CurrentWeight { get; set; }
        public byte[] Pic1 { get; set; }
        public byte[] Pic2 { get; set; }
        public string DelFlag { get; set; }
        public string UpdUser { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime UpdTime { get; set; }
        public string UpdTerm { get; set; }
        public string DCode { get; set; }
        public string ZCode { get; set; }
        public string ACode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Controller:

```
using JQueryPortal.DBContext;
using JQueryPortal.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace JQueryPortal.Controllers
{
    public class jQueryPortalController : Controller
    {
        // GET: jQueryPortal
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        jQueryPortalContext db = new jQueryPortalContext();

        public JsonResult GetVehiclesLists(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)  //Gets the todo Lists.
        {
            int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
            int pageSize = rows;
            var VehicleinLogResults = db.VehicleinLogs.Select(
                    a => new
                    {
                        a.ID,
                        a.SystemRefNo,
                        a.LCode,
                        a.TagNo,
                        a.RecDate,
                        a.RecTime,
                        a.RegNo,
                        a.CurrentWeight,
                        a.DelFlag,
                        a.UpdUser,
                        a.UpdDate,
                        a.UpdTime,
                        a.UpdTerm,
                        a.DCode,
                        a.ZCode,
                        a.ACode
                    });
            int totalRecords = VehicleinLogResults.Count();
            var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
            if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
            {
                VehicleinLogResults = VehicleinLogResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.TagNo);
                VehicleinLogResults = VehicleinLogResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            else
            {
                VehicleinLogResults = VehicleinLogResults.OrderBy(s => s.TagNo);
                VehicleinLogResults = VehicleinLogResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
            }
            var jsonData = new
            {
                total = totalPages,
                page,
                records = totalRecords,
                rows = VehicleinLogResults
            };
            return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        // TODO:insert a new row to the grid logic here
        [HttpPost]
        public string Create([Bind(Exclude = "ID")] VehicleInLog objTodo)
        {
            string msg;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.VehicleinLogs.Add(objTodo);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    msg = "Saved Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "Validation data not successfull";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
            }
            return msg;
        }
        public string Edit(VehicleInLog objTodo)
        {
            string msg;
            try
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(objTodo).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    msg = "Saved Successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    msg = "Validation data not successfull";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                msg = "Error occured:" + ex.Message;
            }
            return msg;
        }
        public string Delete(int Id)
        {
            VehicleInLog vehiclesinlog = db.VehicleinLogs.Find(Id);
            db.VehicleinLogs.Remove(vehiclesinlog);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return "Deleted successfully";
        }
    }
}
```

My JQueryGrid file:

```
$(function () {
    $("#grid").jqGrid({
        url: "/jQueryPortal/GetVehiclesLists",
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames: ['ID', 'SystemRefNo', 'LCode', 'TagNo', 'RecDate', 'RecTime', 'RegNo', 'CurrentWeight', 'DelFlag', 'UpdUser', 'UpdDate', 'UpdTime', 'UpdTerm', 'DCode', 'ZCode', 'ACode'],
        colModel: [
            { key: true, hidden: true, name: 'ID', index: 'ID', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'SystemRefNo', index: 'SystemRefNo', editable: false },
            { key: false, name: 'LCode', index: 'LCode', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'TagNo', index: 'TagNo', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'RecDate', index: 'RecDate', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
            { key: false, name: 'RecTime', index: 'RecTime', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
            { key: false, name: 'RegNo', index: 'RegNo', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'CurrentWeight', index: 'CurrentWeight', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'DelFlag', index: 'DelFlag', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'UpdUser', index: 'UpdUser', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'UpdDate', index: 'UpdDate', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
            { key: false, name: 'UpdTime', index: 'UpdTime', editable: true, formatter: 'date', formatoptions: { newformat: 'd/m/Y' } },
            { key: false, name: 'UpdTerm', index: 'UpdTerm', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'DCode', index: 'DCode', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'ZCode', index: 'ZCode', editable: true },
            { key: false, name: 'ACode', index: 'ACode', editable: true }],
        pager: jQuery('#pager'),
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30, 40],
        height: '100%',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Vehicles List',
        loadonce: true,
        emptyrecords: 'No records to display',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            ID: "0"
        },
        autowidth: true,
        multiselect: true

    }).navGrid('#pager', { edit: true, add: true, del: true, search: true, refresh: true },
        {
            // edit options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: '/jQueryPortal/Edit',
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterEdit: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            width: 500,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // add options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/jQueryPortal/Create",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            width: 500,
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        },
        {
            // delete options
            zIndex: 100,
            url: "/jQueryPortal/Delete",
            closeOnEscape: true,
            closeAfterDelete: true,
            recreateForm: true,
            width: 500,
            msg: "Are you sure you want to delete this task?",
            afterComplete: function (response) {
                if (response.responseText) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                }
            }
        });
});
```

And my Index.cshtml view which is linked to the method Index() in my controller:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Portal";
}
    <title>JQuery Events</title>
    <link href="~/Content/jquery-ui-themes-1.12.0-beta.1/jquery-ui-themes-1.12.0-beta.1/themes/mint-choc/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jQueryPortal.js"></script>

<h2>Portal</h2>

    <div>
        <table id="grid"></table>
        <div id="pager"></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you post your source code? [mcve]

Comment: I have uploaded the source code Håken Lid you can check that!

Comment: I don't know asp.net, unfortunately.

Comment: @RehanSiddiqui: I think that you can use `Convert.ToBase64String(a.Pic1)` to return binary data as string to jqGrid. Then you can add `Pic1` to `colModel` where you use custom formatter which return `"<img src="data:image/png;base64," + cellvalue + " alt="Pic1" />` or something like that. The `image/png` should corresponds the format of data (you can need to fix it to `image/gif` for example). See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme).